# GUI for both desktop and Android applications

Tags: java, android, ajax, user-interface, desktop

I need some kind of GUI tool that will make applications for both Desktop and Android systems.

I did some quick research, but didn't find anything. I was suggested by someone to use PHP and AJAX that is doable. I have never used these languages for such a purpose and the application is in Java, so I have no idea where to start.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Unity could work for you. You would need to use C# instead of java, but they are almost exactly the same syntax wise. A few of the built in methods have different names, but Unity is very easy to make GUI's with.